# Passing non-static member function as std::function

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a similar situation:

```
class A {
    void callingFunction() {
      calledFunction(passedFunction);
    }

    void calledFunction(std::function<void(int)> foo) {
    }

    void passedFunction(int arguments) {
    }
};
```

The compiler error is

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

How do I achieve this without making the `passedFunction` static?

Doing this:

```
calledFunction(std::bind(&A::passedFunction, this);
```

Creates this error:

```
error:static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments foor pointer-to-member
```

Does it mean I have to provide all the arguments in the `callingFunction`when passing the `passedFunction`? This is not possible as the arguments for the `passedFunction` are specified in the `calledFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) capturing `this`, on which `passedFunction` could be called.

```
calledFunction([this](int v) { this->passedFunction(v); });
```

Comment: Yes, but note that depending on what you do with the `std::function`, it's possible to get a `std::function` containing the `A*` pointer which was captured as `this` to live past the lifetime of the `A` object, so be careful about lifetimes.

Comment: This works thank you.